# What is default cache timeout in iOS Safari?

Tags: ios, caching, safari

Can anybody answer this for me please. What is the default cache timeout in iOS Safari?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The default cache policy is `NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy` and
>   the default timeout interval is 60 seconds.

http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLRequest_Class/Reference/Reference.html

(But you really should try [Google](http://www.google.co.uk/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=cache%20timeout%20in%20iOS%20Safari&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&redir_esc=&ei=A0_zTqirBMbDhAfJqqS7AQ) first next time, or just read the documentation)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it for Safari on Mac. Is this applied to Safari on iOS4 (for iPad)?

Comment: I've updated the link in my answer, but did you even bother to look at the iOS documentation?

Comment: Thank you Ashley very much. I did look at the iOS documentation but did not find this.